# Calculating a interest rate tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, finance, numerical-methods, quantitative-finance

I would like to calibrate a interest rate tree using the optimization tool in matlab. Need some guidance on doing it.

The interest rate tree looks like this:

[image]

How it works:

3.73% = 2.5%*exp(2*0.2)

96.40453 = (0.5*100 + 0.5*100)/(1+3.73%)

94.15801 = (0.5*96.40453+ 0.5*97.56098)/(1+2.50%)

The value of 2.5% is arbitrary and the upper node is obtained by multiplying with an exponential of 2*volatility(here it is 20%).

I need to optimize the problem by varying different values for the lower node.

How do I do this optimization in Matlab?

What I have tried so far?

```
InterestTree{1}(1,1) = 0.03;
InterestTree{3-1}(1,3-1)= 2.5/100;
InterestTree{3}(2,:) = 100;
InterestTree{3-1}(1,3-2)= (2.5*exp(2*0.2))/100;
InterestTree{3-1}(2,3-1)=(0.5*InterestTree{3}(2,3)+0.5*InterestTree{3}(2,3-1))/(1+InterestTree{3-1}(1,3-1));
j = 3-2;
InterestTree{3-1}(2,3-2)=(0.5*InterestTree{3}(2,j+1)+0.5*InterestTree{3}(2,j))/(1+InterestTree{3-1}(1,j));
InterestTree{3-2}(2,3-2)=(0.5*InterestTree{3-1}(2,j+1)+0.5*InterestTree{3-1}(2,j))/(1+InterestTree{3-2}(1,j));
```

But I am not sure how to go about the optimization. Any suggestions to improve the code, do tell me..Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the tree to increase in size?  Or are you just optimizing over the value of the "2.5%" parameter?

If it's the latter, there are two ways.  The first is to model the tree using a closed form expression by replacing 2.5% with `x`, which is possible with the tree.  There are nonlinear optimization toolboxes available in Matlab (e.g. more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/using-symbolic-mathematics-with-optimization-toolbox-solvers.html)), but it's been too long since I've done this to give you a more detailed answer.

The seconds is the approach I would immediately do.  I'm interpreting the example you gave, so the equations I'm using may be incorrect - however, the principle of using the for loop is the same.

```
vol = 0.2;
maxival = 100;
val1 = zeros(1,maxival); %Preallocate
finalval = zeros(1,maxival);
for ival=1:maxival
  val1(ival) = i/1000; %Use any scaling you want.  This will go from 0.1% to 10%
  val2=val1(ival)*exp(2*vol);
  x1 = (0.5*100+0.5*100)/(1+val2); %Based on the equation you gave
  x2 = (0.5*100+0.5*100)/(1+val1(ival)); %I'm assuming this is how you calculate the bottom node
  finalval(ival) = x1*0.5+x2*0.5/(1+...);  %The example you gave isn't clear, so replace this with whatever it should be
end

[maxval, indmaxval] = max(finalval);
```

The maximum value is in maxval, and the interest that maximized this is in val1(indmaxval).

Comment: but this is not efficient right? what i mean, it wastes a lot of time search for unwanted values. thought of using the optimization tools in  matlab

Comment: i expect the tree to grow... edited the example to make it the same as the diagram.

Comment: Yes, not efficient, but extremely fast to both code and run.  How is the tree growing?  If more nodes, then which direction?  You may have to do this recursively, or derive the closed form solution based on the summations.

Comment: it is a binominal recombining tree, so for each time interval, there are n+1 nodes at that time interval. thought of using the optimization tools,but not sure how to use..

Comment: OK.  Something similar is done with options (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model).  For loops work fine there.

Comment: but that values are known initially. here we looking for the values.